# Nodejs file direct access in browser

Tags: node.js, plesk

At Plesk server there are nodejs and reactjs build on hit url the build run but when we hit the nodejs file url of js files it open directly on browser means nodejs files are not secure.

Comment: Your server is apparently configured wrong.  It should not be allowed to serve your node.js code files to the client.  In my node servers, I put client-side files in a different directory than server files and the server is never configured to serve anything from the server directory, only from the client directory.  Since a node.js server will serve no files by default, any file it is serving is done by your own code.

Comment: Can you give me structure of that how you implement reactjs and nodejs files

Comment: There are lots of ways to do it.  You need to ask a more specific question about your configuration and/or show us your code and ask some specific question about your code.  Start by putting all your client-side files in a different directory hierarchy from your server files.  Then, any code to serve them should only be allowed to serve files from that client-side directory.  For example, if you're using `express.static()` to serve your client-side files, then just point it at the client sub-directory and the default configuration will not allow it to go above that.

Comment: I have used express.static() and it works it give client side view but when give url of any file it access directly on browser

Comment: So, ONLY point `express.static()` at a directory of client files, NOT at any directory that has server files in it.  That's the simple solution here.  In the future, you really should include the relevant portion of your code in your question so we can help you fix your code directly.  That's how stackoverflow works.  Questions about code should include the relevant code you're asking about - otherwise, we're just guessing and playing 20 questions trying to figure out what your code looks like.

Answer (score 0):

So, it sounds like you are using `express.static()`, yet the user is able to fetch your server files that are not meant to go to the client. That apparently means that you've pointed express.static at a directory that contains your server files.  Instead, you need to point `express.static()` at a directory hierarchy that ONLY contains files meant to be sent to the client.  That means it has to be a separate directory from your server files and it has to not be above your server files directory.

There are many possible places to put it.  Here are a couple ways to organize things:

```
projectDirectory
    serverFiles
        server.js
    clientFiles
        index.html
        login.html
```

Then, when running server code from the serverFiles directory, you would use an `express.static()` like this:

```
const path = require('path');
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, "../clientFiles")));
```

Or, you can do it like this:

```
projectDirectory
    serverFiles
        server.js
        clientFiles
            index.html
            login.html

const path = require('path');
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, "clientFiles")));
```

The idea is that the clientFiles directory hierarchy contains only client-side files and `express.static()` by default will not allow `../` syntax in the URLs to go above it.